# Density function from semialgebra

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable defined on some probability space. Let $f:R\to[0,+\infty)$ be a measurable function such that
$P(X\in[a,b])=\int\limits_{[a,b]}fd\mu$ for every $a,b\in \overline{R}$. How to prove that $f$ is a density function of $X$?

Comment: What is the definition of a density function?

Comment: $f$ is a probability density function iff for each measurable subset $E$ of $\overline{R}$ we have $P(X\in E)=\int\limits_{E}fd\mu$.

Comment: Right! The claim  follows by the uniqueness of measure theorem, doesn't it?

Comment: The only thing that you must show to use the theorem I stated  is that $\lambda (A) = \int_A fd\mu$ is a measure. Can you do that? I think these are all the ingredients you need.

Comment: It is not enough to show that $\lambda$ is a measure. I also have to show that $\lambda(E)=P(X\in E)$. But this is actually my preposition.

I have just proved my preposition. I used for that the approximation theorem $\mu(E\triangle \cup B_i)<\epsilon$.

Comment: If you prove $\lambda$ is a measure, then the rest follows by the uniqueness of measure theorem. So it is enough. Have you heard about that theorem? Or are you not allowed to use it (yet)? How you did also works btw. You can post your answer as a solution to help next generations.

Comment: You are talking abount Radon–Nikodym theorem obviously. If $f$ is a non-negative measurable function then $\lambda(E)=\int\limits_{E}fd\mu$ is a measure even if $\lambda(E)\not=P(X\in E)$ for some $E$.

Comment: No not the Radon Nikodym Thm. See how to use the uniqueness on my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}$I have seen in your comment that you have solved it using the approximation theorem. I'll show you how to do it with [the uniqueness of measure theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Uniqueness_of_Measures). I'll put everything you need from that theorem in this post.

> **Definition ($\pi$-system):** A collection $\Pi$ of subsets of $\Omega$ is called a $\pi$-system if for all $A,B\in \Pi$   we have $A\cap B\in \Pi$.

Now I state the theorem:

> **Theorem**. Let $\Pi\in \Omega$ be a $\pi$-system and $\mathcal{F}=\sigma(\Pi)$. Furthermore let $\P_1$ and
>   $\P_2$ be two probability measures on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$. Let $\Pi$ be a 
>    $\pi$-system
>   and assume that $\P_1(A)=\P_2(A)$ for all $A\in \Pi$. Then $\P_1=\P_2$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$.

We set $\Pi=\{ [a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}\ | \ a<b  \}\cup \emptyset$, you can easily verify that $\Pi$ is indeed a $\pi$-system. Furthermore $\sigma(\Pi)$ is the borel sigma algebra so $\sigma(\Pi)=\mathcal B$.

Define the set function $\lambda:\mathcal B \to [0,\infty)$  by $$\lambda(E)=\int_E fd\mu$$ Showing that this is a probability measure is easy. Note that $\lambda(\mathbb R) = \P(X\in \mathbb{R})=1$ and $\lambda(\emptyset) = 0$. You can verify that for  $A_1, A_2, ... \in \mathcal B$ a countable collection of mutually disjoint sets we have $\lambda(\cup_i A_i)=\sum_i \lambda(A_i)$.

Note that $\P(X\in A) = X_\#\P(A)$ and we know $X_\#\P$ is a measure. It is given that $X_\#\P(A)=\lambda(A)$ for all $A\in\Pi$. So by the uniqueness theorem we have $X_\#\P(A)=\lambda(A)$ for all $A\in \mathcal B$, i.e. $$\P(X\in A) = \int_A fd\mu$$ for all $A\in\mathcal B$

So $f$ is a density for $X$.