# Reference for: a Lebesgue integrable function and its rearrangements have the same Lebesgue integral.

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

In http://kunklet.people.cofc.edu/condint.pdf there's the sentence at the beginning of the Introduction:

"An elementary fact from measure theory states that a Lebesgue integrable function
and its rearrangements have the same Lebesgue integral."

Can someone please refer a book that proves this statement? Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that you could prove it yourself.

Comment: @herb steinberg : Haha, yes, but I need a book reference :D

Comment: Is Exercise 1.4.38 on page 103 of Terry Tao's book "An introduction to measure theory" at https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/gsm-126-tao5-measure-book.pdf a more general result that has the statement "An elementary fact from measure theory states that a Lebesgue integrable function and its rearrangements have the same Lebesgue integral." as its specialized corollary?

Comment: @herb steinberg how would you prove the statement please?

Comment: It depends on how the Lebesgue integral was first developed.  I first encountered it using the horizontal strip approach.  In this approach, the horizontal strips would give the same value for the rearranged function.

Comment: indeed! But how is it proven? This is the Lebesgue integral version of the fact that absolutely convergent series can be rearranged at will. There are many subtleties involved though...

Comment: I guess you must start with a precise definition of  rearrangement.

Comment: it's given in linked paper in question

Comment: I put it together as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $f_\#\mu=\mu\circ f^{-1}$, namely the law of $f$ under the Lebesgue measure. Since $f$ and $g$ have the same distribution it follows that $f_\#\mu=g_\#\mu$ ([uniqueness of measure](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Uniqueness_of_Measures)). Moreover one has by the [change of measure/variables formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) 
$$\int_\mathbb R f(x) \, d\mu(x) =\int_\mathbb R x\, df_\#\mu(x) $$
Using $f_\#\mu=g_\#\mu$ we conclude that
$$\int f\, d\mu=\int g\, d\mu$$
Surely, you have to verify why the uniqueness of measure theorem applies.

Comment: Yes, but I need a book reference. Do you happen to know of any book that has this proven, please?

Comment: @anonymous everything here is actually basic measure theory. What did we use? Change of measure formula and uniqueness of measure, both of them could be found by just googling.

Comment: I was expecting some respectable book about measure theory, especially about the rearrangements... Googling gives... lots of very varied results :D A renown book on it would help tremendously!

Comment: @anonymous I have put some links to the theorems I have used. To be honest, I don't have a book suggestion about rearrangements.

Comment: How would you verify why the uniqueness of measure theorem applies please?

Comment: @anonymous Check this answer, where something similar is done: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2553739/349501

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition in the link. Let a strip be defined by $[a,b)$. Then from the definition of rearrangement the measure of the set $(x:a\le  f(x)\lt b)$ is the same as the measure of the set $(x:a\le g(x)\lt b)$. Therefore the strip approach leads to the integrals being equal.   In case it isn't obvious, use the fact that the sets $(x:f(x)\lt b)-(x:f(x)\lt a)=(:a\le f(x)\lt b)$ so the rearrangement definition applies to strips.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be trivial... I  can't believe it's this easy. I have to convince myself still... Will give it few days for thinking about it. Thanks, will chime in!

Comment: The problem I'm having with convincing myself is about the statement being very general, about all Lebesgue integrable functions, so what if $f(x)$ is not bounded and what if integration is over $x\in [1,\infty)$...

Comment: The domain of x is irrelevant, since we are dealing with measures of the function within strips.  To avoid complications, omit the strip containing the x axis, which will shrink to $0$ width eventually.  If $f(x)$ is not bounded, then the sums for the strip approximation will have an infinite number of terms, but will converge as long as the function is integrable in the first place.  When you rearrange, the terms of the strip approximations for $f$ and $g$ are identical term by term as long as the summation order is determined by strip order.